# Как правильно реализовать цикл в цикле?

Tags: c#

```
private void carbonFiberButton11_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = PairConcat(Encrypt(), bina());
        }


public static string PairConcat(string Encrypt, string bina)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            int i = 0;

        for(; i<Encrypt.Length & i < bina.Length; i++)
        {
            result.Append(Encrypt[i].ToString());
            result.Append(bina[i].ToString());
        }
        result.Append(Encrypt.Substring(i));
        result.Append(bina.Substring(i));
        return result.ToString();

        }
```

Работает это так:

string bina = "12345", string Encrypt = "абвгд"
И в textbox выводится - 1а2б3в4г5д. 
Как теперь это реализовать, если строки разной длины. Допустим, bina всегда "12345", а Encrypt меняется (хоть 100 символов). Как вызвать повторение bina по всей длине Encrypt?

Comment: брать остаток от деления `i` на длину bina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой способ сделать так

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        char[] ch = { 'а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т','у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ь','ы','ъ','э','ю','я' };
        txt_result.Text = PairConcat(ch, "12345");
    }

    public static string PairConcat(char[] Encrypt, string bina)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        int j = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < Encrypt.Length; i++)
        {
            if (j > 4) j = 0;
            result.Append(string.Format("{0}{1}", bina[j],  Encrypt[i]));
            j++;
        }
        //result.Append(Encrypt.Substring(i));
        //result.Append(bina.Substring(i));
        return result.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: Мне кажется, добавлять bina[j] и Encrypt[j] в StringBuilder по одиночке было бы значительно быстрее, чем вашим способом (через string.Format), особенно для больших массивов.

Comment: @Philippe, Вариантов много. Я лишь показал самый простой. Чтобы было от чего отталкиваться в дальнейшем.

Comment: @Philippe, Сейчас проверил по времени. Да по одиночке добавлять быстрее. На 0,03 миллисекунд быстрее. Так что не значительно быстрее, но все же быстрее.